# If it is technology specific, is it still a design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

I went to a .NET user group meeting tonight, and part of it revolved around the model-view-view model pattern, and it got me wondering if this qualified as a pattern.
The issue I have is that M-V-VM is extremely technology specific. If you do not use WPF and its binding mechanism, I don't see how you could use that pattern.
By contrast, most "classic" patterns are largely technology agnostic. The biggest assumption they make is that the language used is object-oriented, and typically supports inheritance.  Beyond that, classic patterns are mostly about stating a general design problem, and proposing an approach to resolving it - but multiple implementations or variations are possible.
My question is then where do you draw the line, between what is a design pattern and what is a recommendation on how to use a very specific framework? If you know how to implement it and what language and technology you need to use to do so, is it still a pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can the underlying concepts that are necessary for the "approach" to work be re-implemented on another platform without violating any patents, intellectual property, or obscene amounts of work? If so, I'd say we can definitely still call it a design pattern in the sense you're getting at - just a new one that isn't easy to do widely *yet*. (Though even platform-specific approaches can still be design patterns for the smaller community that can use them).

Do also keep in mind that MVVM is just a specific implementation of the **Presentation Model Pattern** [presented by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html), which is certainly "classic" as you say, and platform-agnostic.

"Nothing new under the sun" as they say, just different arrangements of the same ideas. Principles are refined all the time, rarely new ones invented.

Answer (score 4):

Patterns are not an island in some sea of other things.  Its not black and white that something is a pattern or not; all patterns can be layed out on a scale and be various shades of gray between generic and domain specific, between process and code and pretty much any two other goalposts you happen to pick.

If its a recipe that's worth sharing or reusing in even *slightly* different circumstances, its a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Design Patterns are often dependent on the programming language and technology in use: for example, DPs dealing with explicit resource ownership play badly with garbage-collected languages, one working around the limitations of compile-time typing play badly with dynamic languages, and so on -- that's normal, perfectly fine, essentially inevitable.

"A recommendation" differs from "a design pattern" not by technology context, but by breadth and especially depth: a proper DP identifies two or more independently developed uses of similar approaches, delves deeper to see what common "forces" they were dealing with, and harps on from there, in a beautiful but heavy-weight meta-format. By contrast, a recommdendation is much less formal, deep, and broad!

DPs are never **invented**, they are **discovered** by pondering over existing code (two or more independently developed occurrences) that deal with similar situations, identifying the commonalities as "forces" driving the solutions, etc, etc. "DP" is such a popular, catchy term that it's used FAR more widely than it should be -0- go back to the sources and read, or re-read, Alexander's [Timeless Way of Building](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195024028) and his other works, if you've lost your way through the thicket of DP's buzzwordhood, they'll help you find the trail again!

Answer (score 0):

> If you do not use WPF and its binding
>   mechanism, I don't see how you could
>   use that pattern.

Silverlight and Moonlight also support MVVM.

Comment: Point taken. That being said, Silverlight is more or less a subset of WPF (I assume that's true of Moonlight too). I am using WPF in a broad sense, using XAML-based views.

Answer (score 0):

"Languages are based off paradigms", each paradigm has different ways to solve a problem. Design patterns happen to be common solutions, doesn't matter if it's language specific or not.